# Get external access to SharedPreferences in Android

Tags: android, file, sharedpreferences, external

I have a question and couldn't find an answer till yet.
In my application, I'm saving Strings in SharedPreferences. Those are various user data like username, password, time and so on.
I need those Preferences on two sites. One is another activity, where i load the information. this works fine.

My problem is, that I want access to those Preferences from outside. This means, i want it in a seperate txt file. Is there a way to get them in a txt file? So that I can open the file from my computer and look into it?

Sorry for my bad English.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to write the shared preferences so you can look at them for debugging purposes, you can just use the Java FileOutputStream or similar to write to an arbitrary file.

See: [Saving Files](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

As an alternative, you can actually look at the shared preferences file using adb and copying the file elsewhere more accessible to you.

Ex:
adb.exe devices // Find your device serial
adb.exe -s [SERIAL] // Connect to your device
run-as [YOUR_APP_PACKAGE] // Obtain appropriate permissions to access your package
cd /data/data/[YOUR_APP_PACKAGE] // You'll find your shared prefs in here

See: [Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)

Comment: thanks. I've looked into it and it seems doable.
But one question do I still have. 
Can I write my whole "SharedPreferences" into a file or do I have to write each string into it?

Comment: You can use something like getAll() on the shared preferences object to obtain a map of all the key/values, then iterate over the map writing each pair to your file.

Or use a FileInputStream to read from the shared prefs file directly and FileOutputStream to write every character read to a new file.

Comment: ...would you have an example of something like this? 
As I'm new to Android, I don't know many of those functions...sorry :/